# Python not accepting Tamil scripts, letter

Tags: python, character-encoding

Below is my simple code for sending WhatsApp message in Python. The message is typed in footer.txt file in the program folder. It recognizes only English scripts. I need to encode **Tamil** letters also.

```
import pywhatkit

with open("footer.txt", encoding='utf8') as f:
    pywhatkit.sendwhats_image("E9wnucCUpBpD1aizIUyLv6", "E:\\PythonFiles\\Music.jpg", f.read(), 10)
```

Comment: Is the problem reading from the file (are you sure it's UTF-8 encoded?) or having `sendwhatis_image` encode the resulting `str` value?

Comment: What program did you use to create `footer.txt`? What did you do to ensure that that program was using UTF-8?

Comment: your call does not match the signature of `sendwhats_image` https://github.com/Ankit404butfound/PyWhatKit/blob/9d02ec917a803cbe5d8e196c46b760a3ac9db522/pywhatkit/whats.py#L142 ...I suggest used named keyword args to ensure the values you are sending match up as intended

Comment: @chepner yes it is utf-8 for english scripts. i need show tamil scripts.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy no prgram required. it is manually created with some Tamil scripts. i need to encode it to the porgram.

Comment: Where does the Tamil text come from? UTF-8 can encode *all* scripts. In fact, `sednwhats_image` doesn't seem to require you to know about encodings; you provide it a `str` value (which is just Unicode code points; presumably WhatKit handles encoding the strings as necessary).

Comment: @chepner i have manually footer.txt file with message in English. it works fine. It is not working if I replace to Tamil texts, as you said pywhatkit handle ONLY English scripts.

Comment: UTF-8 can be used for Tamil. The entire point of Unicode is to have a single set of codepoints that works for all languages. (Not all _fonts_ support all codepoints, but that's a separate problem).

Comment: I didn't say `pywhatkit` handles only English scripts. I said it appears to encode the `str` value (which can contain *any* Unicode code points: English, Tamil, Cyrillic, Arabic, etc) itself. For example, "English and தமிழ்".

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Elaborate "*It is not working if I replace to Tamil texts*". What happens, exactly?

Comment: @JosefZpywhatkit works fine sending English Texts but not working for Tamil texts.